# su pass password to script

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I am trying to write a script that will run the following commands:

```
sudo su
runmqsc_result=`su -c "runmqsc QMGR < /home/rob/query_queue.txt" -m "mqm"`
```

My issue however, is that these commands are run as part of a shell script, by user that is in the sudoers file. However, obviously sudo su asks for the password of the user running it.

What I need to do is to pass the password to sudo su so that the script will run automatically. How can I do this?

p.s: I can't change the permissions for running "runmqsc"...it HAS to be run as user mqm which needs to be switched to from the root user.

Comment: Just configure `sudo` to allow executing `runmqsc` (possibly with the specific arguments) as user `mqm` without password—that's the primary purpose of `sudo`. The `su` is of course superfluous here; `sudo` already does its job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From `man sudo`:

```
-S    The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard
      input instead of the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a
      newline character.
```

So, while it **defies all security principles**, `echo 'password' | sudo -S su [...]` should work.

---

Alternatively, you could make your script writeable only by root and add the following to `/etc/sudoers` to allow the user `johndoe` to run it with root priviledges without having to enter his password:

```
johndoe ALL = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/your/script
```

The part *writeable only by root* is important to prevent `johndoe` from modifying the script and executing arbitrary commands as root.

Comment: Defying all security principles I did this in Busybox:

`echo password | su -c reboot`

Comment: I believe the question was about passing to `su`, though; in my case, the machine in question does not and will never have `sudo` on it, so this solution is pretty much dead for su alone.

Answer (score 1):

This solution work by using 'script' command from the 'bsdutiles' package that setup a pty (a terminal). The 'sleep' command is there to prevent sending the password before the 'su' command is ready to read it. The 'tail' command remove the "Password:" input line issued by 'su'.

```
 { sleep 1; echo rootpassword } | script -qc 'su -c "runmqsc QMGR < /home/rob/query_queue.txt" -m "mqm"' /dev/null | tail -n +2
```

Beware that the rootpassword could be see in many ways (history, ps, /proc/, etc...). Start the command with a space to at least avoid history recording.