# How to login automatically from one normal user to other user not using sudo

Tags: shell

I am trying to build one script for my customization login from one user to another on multiple servers , for that  i need to login from my user to another user on same server with out using  sudo command for that  I am using "echo "passward" | su - oracle " but it won't work, I am searching  all forms they  are suggesting sudo . but I don't want to use sudo. simple I looking switch user from my user to other on single command.

Comment: The easy way (if you have root access and can add yourself to the `wheel` group) is to edit `/etc/pam.d/su` and add/uncomment the following two lines `auth            sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid` and `auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid` which will then allow you so `su user` without a password.

Comment: no I am regular user, I have two accounts on my server one is my account and again switch back to install user  awdmw

Comment: Understood, but if you have root access, you can add your normal user to `wheel` (or the `sudo` group if that is what your distro uses) and make the changes. Then you can switch from one user to any other. If you don't have `root` access to set it up, then you are kinda stuck. My concern with what you are doing is that I'm not sure that `su` will accept a password from `stdin`. I haven't messed with it, but piping a password to anything is a big security issue.

Comment: I want to passing  a password on run time like variable, like (echo "$pass |  su awdmw ) but its is not working when I am using in stdin also.

Comment: See: [**su pass password to script**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164222/su-pass-password-to-script)