# 'su' by using 'script' in Docker returns different results compared to the standard environment

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ubuntu

I need to request certain commands via `su` including password in one line.
I found a solution and it is working in a standard environment (Ubuntu) (more about solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741462/11643108)):

```
{ sleep 1; echo password; } | script -qc 'su -l user -c id' /dev/null | tail -n +2
```

But I am faced with the problem that this solution is not suitable in a Docker container environment

`Script` terminates the command without waiting for `echo` and as a result i get:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide more info like what exactly you're trying also the dockerfile you used.

Comment: In general you'd never use the `script` command, or `su`, or any sort of password in the context of a Docker container.  Can you say a little more about the higher-level problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This question is not to understand that it is not good idea to echo the password to su for security reasons or the availability of other methods.I'm only interested in why the same command behaves is different in container and standard environment. .

Answer (score 0):

Passing the password for `su` via `stdin` is problematic for various reasons: the biggest one is probably that your password will end up in the history.

You could instead:

- Call the entire script as the specific user and thus enter the password manually
- Use sudo with the appropriate *NOPASSWD* sudoers configuration
- In your case you are using docker, so you could just set the `USER` in your `Dockerfile`